# How to track mysql query performance with php?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, performance-testing

Is using simple `get_memory_usage()` reliable method to track memory usage of specific mysql query?

Does `get_memory_usage()` count also sql process or is that separate?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you are asking about [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php). It counts memory used by php script only. Mysql is a separate process, running independently from your php script.

Answer (score 0):

I found apache ab (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). It doesn't tell you memory_usage but time needed to complete request. With 10000 requests you get then average time for entire request. This was fine solution for me because it clearly showed if specific query toke too much resources or not.